# More efficient way to write jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better way to write this function? I'm pretty sure I only need one function here but I don't know how to write it!

```
(function(jQuery){
    jQuery.fn.codeexists = function(code) {
        var codeexist = false;
        jQuery('#fault-list-tbl tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
            var id = jQuery(this).find('.fault-tbl-code').html();
            if (id == code) {
                codeexist = true;
            };
        });
        if (codeexist) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    }; 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Start with `(function($){` and use freely the argument `$`

Comment: You don't need the outer function. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks but I need to use `jQuery` as I'm working with a joomla site so `$` causes conflicts etc.!

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes exactly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be much simpler:

```
jQuery.fn.codeexists = function(code) {
    return jQuery('#fault-list-tbl tbody tr .fault-tbl-code').filter(function() {
        return this.html() === code;
    }).length > 0;
};
```

`filter` filters the elements down to only the ones which have an `html` of `code`, and `length` is how many elements. Therefore, if there's more than 0 (`length > 0`) elements which have `code` as their `html`, it returns true.

Comment: He's not using `id=code` but `html=code` this would require different html structure.

Comment: That's not what the question asked, it's asking to check the html, not the id. Also, why would you need to do such a nested query? If the element has an id, then `#code` would suffice.

Comment: @megawac Whoops, confusing variable names. Edited.

Comment: @Doorknob Thanks thats great! I knew it had to be simpler than what I had! Would you mind explaining how this works? I think I get the filter bit but not sure about the `length > 0` part

Comment: @doovers `filter` filters the elements down to only the ones which have an `html` of `code`, and `length` is how many elements. Therefore, if there's more than 0 elements which have `code` as their `html`, it returns true.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write it like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.codeexists = function(code) {
        var codeexist = false;
        $('#fault-list-tbl tbody tr .fault-tbl-code').html(function (i, id) {
            if (id == code) {
                codeexist = true;
            };
        });
        return codeexist;
    }; 
})(jQuery);
```